Is there a way to change the Solidworks properties after a drawing has been placed through VBA
I'm trying to update a Solidworks VBA script to adjust properties of a view after it has already been placed and am unsure how to actually do this. In the GUI once I select the view I can edit these properties (e.g. display state, scale, dimension type) via the property manager and the drawing view tab. If I try to make a macro that I can then use as my baseline I only get my the selection of the drawing view from SelectByID2.
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Drawing View1", "DRAWINGVIEW", x, y, z, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
Part.ClearSelection2 True

Is there a way to actually modify these properties once the drawing view has already been placed?

Don't have sw to test but guess this can help. Here you can find some examples on the IView Interface

It's possible to change a DrawingView after it has been placed.
You can find documentation on the IView Interface Members here
The code below doubles the selected view scale. The code is from here
Option Explicit
Sub main()
    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swDraw As SldWorks.DrawingDoc
    Dim swSelMgr As SldWorks.SelectionMgr
    Dim swView As SldWorks.View
    Dim vScaleRatio As Variant
    Dim bRet As Boolean
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swDraw = swModel
    Set swSelMgr = swModel.SelectionManager
    Set swView = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObject6(1, -1)
    vScaleRatio = swView.ScaleRatio
    Debug.Print "File = " & swModel.GetPathName
    Debug.Print "  View = " & swView.Name
    Debug.Print "    Use sheet scale = " & CBool(swView.UseSheetScale)
    Debug.Print "    Original scale ratio = " & vScaleRatio(0) & ":" & vScaleRatio(1)
    Debug.Print "    Original decimal scale value = " & swView.ScaleDecimal
    ' Increase scale values
    ' Changing scale sets IView::UseSheetScale to false
    vScaleRatio = swView.ScaleRatio
    swView.ScaleDecimal = swView.ScaleDecimal * 2#
    vScaleRatio = swView.ScaleRatio
    Debug.Print ""
    Debug.Print "    Use sheet scale = " & CBool(swView.UseSheetScale)
    Debug.Print "    New scale ratio = " & vScaleRatio(0) & ":" & vScaleRatio(1)
    Debug.Print "    New decimal scale value = " & swView.ScaleDecimal
    ' Rebuild to see the scaled drawing view
    bRet = swModel.EditRebuild3: Debug.Assert bRet
End Sub



Here you can find documentation on the IView Interface and more links to examples.

First, get the ModelDoc2, then convert it to a DrawingDoc, get the view object through the DrawingDoc's GetFirstView method, and iterate through the drawing view object to get the view information you want. Here is the code:
  Option Explicit

 

Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks

Dim swModel As ModelDoc2

Dim swView As View

Dim swDraw As DrawingDoc

 Dim vScaleRatio As Variant

Sub main()
 

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks

Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc

Set swDraw = swModel


Set swView = swDraw.GetFirstView
   
    Do While Not swView Is Nothing


        Debug.Print "  " & swView.Name
        vScaleRatio = swView.ScaleRatio
        swView.ScaleDecimal = swView.ScaleDecimal * 2#
        Debug.Print "    Use sheet scale = " & CBool(swView.UseSheetScale)
        Debug.Print "    New scale ratio = " & vScaleRatio(0) & ":" & vScaleRatio(1)
        Debug.Print "    New decimal scale value = " & swView.ScaleDecimal

        Set swView = swView.GetNextView

    Loop
    

 End Sub

in @solidWorking's answer,you can see IView interface.
